# Serialization does work in sample project, but not in app

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

In an app I am developing, I found a problem when serializing a custom class.It's a class derived from a Generic Tree class, so let's call it DerivedFromTree. The Tree class is in another assembly.

```
[Serializable]
class DerivedFromTree : Tree<UnderlyingTreeType>
{
    ...
}
```

To isolate my problem I created a new console project, added the DerivedFromTree files and its dependencies and added a reference to the DLL in which Tree resides. Then added the following code:

```
DerivedFromTree dft = new DerivedFromTree("label");
UnderlyingTreeType utt = new UnderlyingTreeType(...);
dft.AddChild(utt);
utt = new UnderlyingTreeType(...);
dft.AddChild(utt);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(ms, dft);
ms.Position = 0; // position stream to 0
DerivedFromTree dft_result = (DerivedFromTree)bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

After running this code in the sample project, dft_result contains a valid DerivedFromTree with its children. However, if I put the same code in my original application, I get an exception when calling bf.Serialize:

```
{System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'MyAssembly.Tree`1[[UnderlyingTreeType, Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' from assembly 'Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   in System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
   in Class.Function() in C:\...\FileName.cs:line XXX}
```

Any idea about what could be happening there?

**Update:** The classes Tree, DerivedFromTree, UnderlyingTreeType and all its dependencies are marked as [Serializable]. Failing to do so would result in the small console project throwing an exception. If I remove the [Serializable] attribute from Tree class, the console project throws the exact same error as the original app.

Comment: Did you have you marked the Classes as [Serilizable]?

Comment: @user751975: Yes, I have. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Better Edit in the [serializable] attrs

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your object has **delegate fields** which [may or may not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163902.aspx#S1) throw an exception when being serialized.
Make sure you mark delegates nonserializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{   
   [NonSerialized]   
   EventHandler m_MyEvent; 
}
```

For events, you should specify `field` attribute qualifier when applying `NonSerialized`:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyPublisher
{
   [field:NonSerialized]   
   public event EventHandler MyEvent; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No delegates, though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that `SerializibleAttribute` has it's `IsInherited` property set to `false`. If your code looked exactly as posted above (without decorating `DerivedFromTree` by `[Serializible]`) it would not work...

Answer (score 0):

Request you to go through the section of

1. Steps in the Serialization Process
2. Serialization Guidelines

of article Object Serialization

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx

and check if you haven't missed anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed now. I removed the reference to the DLL containing the Tree class and added it again, and suddenly everything worked.

I think I'm going to delete the question, as it doesn't seem very useful...

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: It seems I can delete the answer because it has answers, so I won't delete it :-/